# Get the correct post id for all post and page in header.php

Tags: id

I want to get the current post/page id outside the loop (in header.php) and use this id for Advanced Custom Fields plugin to get the fields.

But i cant get the correct id from front page, archive page(tag, author, category...etc).

Here is the code

```
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
  $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
  echo 'post id' . $post_id;
} elseif ( is_shop() ) {
  $post_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
  echo 'post id' . $post_id;
} else {
  $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
  echo 'post id' . $post_id
}
```

One more question, any better method to get the id for all of the page outside loop? I just worry my code is still miss some of the page type.

Comment: `global $post; echo $post_id = $post->ID;` anywhere will do the job for you.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam not true, what about archive pages. And what about a bad query or bad code that changed the `$post` global

Comment: @PieterGoosen Right. I overlook the `header.php` portion. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_queried_object_id()` will return the ID of the current single post or page being viewed, as well as the static front page. For any type of archive page (*except date, custom post type and home archives*), the following will be returned:

- Category ID of the category archive being viewed
- Tag ID of the current tag archive being viewed
- Author ID of the current author archive being viewed
- Term ID for the current term page being viewed

If this is not the case in your case, you, your theme or a plugin you are using is in all probability using `query_posts` somewhere. `query_posts` breaks the main query object and resets the main query object to the custom query using `query_posts`. This is why you should **never ever** ue `query_posts`